# Kernel dies when trying to compute coefficients in a linear sum involving expressions like b[1,2][3,4]

Tags: functions, summation, crash, coefficients

The following happens on 11.0.1.0:
Have

```
fun=a[1][5,1]b[1,2][1,1]+a[1][4,1]b[1,2][1,2]+a[1][5,2]b[1,2][2,1]
   +a[1][4,2]b[1,2][2,2]+a[1][5,3]b[1,2][3,1]+a[1][4,3]b[1,2][3,2]
   +a[1][5,4]b[1,2][4,1]-a[2][1,2]b[1,2][4,1]+a[1][4,4]b[1,2][4,2]
   -a[2][2,2]b[1,2][4,2]+a[1][5,5]b[1,2][5,1]-a[2][1,1]b[1,2][5,1]
   +a[1][4,5]b[1,2][5,2]-a[2][2,1]b[1,2][5,2]+a[1][5,6]b[1,2][6,1]
   +a[1][4,6]b[1,2][6,2]+a[1][5,7]b[1,2][7,1]+a[1][4,7]b[1,2][7,2]
   +a[1][5,8]b[1,2][8,1]+a[1][4,8]b[1,2][8,2]+a[1][3,1]b[1,3][1,1]
   -a[3][1,3]b[1,3][1,1]+a[1][2,1]b[1,3][1,2]-a[3][2,3]b[1,3][1,2]
   +a[1][1,1]b[1,3][1,3]-a[3][3,3]b[1,3][1,3]+a[1][3,2]b[1,3][2,1]
   -a[3][1,2]b[1,3][2,1]+a[1][2,2]b[1,3][2,2]-a[3][2,2]b[1,3][2,2]
   +a[1][1,2]b[1,3][2,3]-a[3][3,2]b[1,3][2,3]+a[1][3,3]b[1,3][3,1]
   -a[3][1,1]b[1,3][3,1]+a[1][2,3]b[1,3][3,2]-a[3][2,1]b[1,3][3,2]
   +a[1][1,3]b[1,3][3,3]-a[3][3,1]b[1,3][3,3]+a[1][3,4]b[1,3][4,1]
   +a[1][2,4]b[1,3][4,2]+a[1][1,4]b[1,3][4,3]+a[1][3,5]b[1,3][5,1]
   +a[1][2,5]b[1,3][5,2]+a[1][1,5]b[1,3][5,3]+a[1][3,6]b[1,3][6,1]
   +a[1][2,6]b[1,3][6,2]+a[1][1,6]b[1,3][6,3]+a[1][3,7]b[1,3][7,1]
   +a[1][2,7]b[1,3][7,2]+a[1][1,7]b[1,3][7,3]+a[1][3,8]b[1,3][8,1]
   +a[1][2,8]b[1,3][8,2]+a[1][1,8]b[1,3][8,3]
```

Trying

```
vars = Select[Variables[fun], Head[Head[#]] == b &];
Union[Flatten[CoefficientList[fun, vars]]]
```

kills the kernel.

If I take only few first summands, the result is computed fairly quickly. When gradually adding summands, it works more and more slowly and seems to need more and more memory. It dies when about 3/4 of the summands are added.

Why? How to deal with such cases? Of course I can redenote my variables but I would prefer to work with them the way they are here.

Comment: The crash is a task for Wolfram Support, not for us. The best you can expect regarding the crash from us is to check if it is reproducible in all platforms and versions. 
Looking for a more efficient way to deal with your problem in Wolfram Language is a valid question. So, I would first report the crash to Wolfram support, then edit your question saying you reported the crash but still are looking for alternative efficient approaches.

Comment: @rhermans I added information about the version. As for the rest, - there is a [tag:bug] tag, I am just hesitant to add it since it may turn out it is not a bug and I am doing something wrong. When I ask "Why?", I mean precisely that, I ask for expert opinion whether the reason is a bug or my error or something else.

Comment: A crash is never a feature, always a bug, and therefore necessarily a job for Wolfram Support. You should not use the bug tag until is confirmed by the community.

Comment: @rhermans Sorry, I am confused by your last comment. Do you say that this is definitely a bug?

Comment: How could be that crashing is not a bug? The program is supposed to detect running out of memory, infinite recursion, and so on. BTW, this is getting too chatty, probably we should move away from the comments section into the [chat].

Comment: It could be that it ran out of memory. Probably should abort with a mesage in that case. Will investigate.

Comment: It seems to be crashing in the `Flatten` step. Been difficult to track to its lair but I'm cautiously ptimistic.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you! Although I found a solution it is still good to know where is the bottleneck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vars` is a list of 40 element, so, given your expression involves quadratic powers of some variables, `CoefficientList` appears to generate 40-folded list with too many elements (5566277615616, to be precise). So you run out of memory. Meanwhile, most of those elements are zeros (except 36 elements). Use `CoefficientRules` instead. In particular,

```
Last/@CoefficientRules[fun, vars]
```

will have the same effect as your (not working) line

```
Union[Flatten[CoefficientList[fun, vars]]]
```

PS: here is how I got the number 5566277615616:

```
Times @@ (1 + Max /@ Transpose[First /@ CoefficientRules[fun, vars]])
```

PPS: The bottom line is when you think of using `CoeffficientList` command, consider `CoeffficientRules` as a much better alternative. I myself mostly use `CoeffficientList` only for one-variable case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `CoefficientList` becomes enormous in this case. I managed to obtain what I want using `Table[Coefficient[fun,v],{v,vars}]`